# How to store a output from a function in Session Storage?

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I have a function which gives out random alphanumeric strings every time
`Math.random().toString(36).replace('0.', '')` 
I want to store the output of this particular function in the session storage and have that value till the session is closed. Is there anyway I could do this?

What I have tried:- `sessionStorage.setItem('verifcode', function myfync(){Math.random().toString(36).replace('0.', '') })`
What happened?:- I set up a alert function to check if it was working, and I only got the `{Math.random().toString(36).replace('0.', '') }` in return

If there is no way of directly doing this, other methods are also appreciated.

Comment: Just just have to give a value to session storage, not a function. So: `sessionStorage.setItem('verifcode', Math.random().toString(36).replace('0.', ''))`

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! If possible, I'd also like the string to be longer, around 75 characters. How could I do that?

Edit:- I checked, and the value of the sessionstorage is changing every time I open a new page in the same domain and the same tab. Any way I could avoid that?

Comment: You could check if a value has already been set in the session storage with`sessionStorage.getItem('verifcode') === null`. And then set the session value if the comparison evaluates to `true`.